# how can i use smtp config thats received from form?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

i want to use config that i get from html form and i dont want to get it from **config/mail.php** or **.env** file
how can i do that in **laravel 8**

```
/**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->from($address = 'contact@example.com', $name = $this->data['from'])
                    ->subject($this->data['subject'])
                    ->view('mail.view')
                    ->smtp('mail.example.com')
                    ->port('587')
                    ->username('username')
                    ->password('pass')
                    ->smtp('mail.example.com')
                    ->with(['message' => $this->data['message']]);
    }
```

Comment: you want to send email base on user input, right?

Comment: yes or from database

Answer (score 0):

you can use [swiftmailer](https://swiftmailer.symfony.com/docs/introduction.html) to send any type of mail you want (laravel use this under the hood):

```
    $transport = (new Swift_SmtpTransport("smtp.gmail.com", "587", "tls"))
    ->setUsername('username')
    ->setPassword('pass');

    $mailer = new Swift_Mailer($transport);

    $message = (new Swift_Message("subject"))               // email subject
        ->setFrom(['contact@example.com' => "sender name"]) // sender mail and display name
        ->setTo("receiver@gmail.com")                       // replace with your receiver mail variable
        ->setBody("<h2>Test</h2>", 'text/html');

    $result = $mailer->send($message);                      // send the mail
```

if you want to send from queue instead of in controller directly, you can create queue and pass mail parameter to queue construct